# Is there a way to check for if certain conditions are true on the second call of a function?

Tags: javascript

So I want to call a function

```
myfunction();
```

I want to be able to have my code call it once and be fine but if my code calls it a second time, I want to check to see if certain conditions are true and if they are, I want the function to not run. If these conditions aren't true, then I want the function to run as usual. I just want to know if something specific is true only for a second call to the function and not allow my function to run again until those conditions aren't true anymore.

```
if(condition) {
//don't run function code for as long as this is true. 
}
else{
//business as usual, run the code
}
```

I want to do this always on the second call to the function. So first function call, no checking. On a second call, check. On a 3rd call no checking, on the 4th call check etc. Basically, every other call to the function, check to see if certain conditions are true
and if they are, don't run the function code. I would very much appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy enough.  Since what you're looking for is basically a function that modifies its behavior according to some internal state, it's an ideal application for objects:

```
var o = {
    calls: 0,
    fn: function(){
        if(++this.calls%2){
            console.log('odd call');
        } else {
            console.log('even call');
        }
    }
}
```

If you absolutely must have a function only (no object), you can use an [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to return a function:

```
var fn = (function(){
    var calls = 0;
    return function(){
        if(++calls%2){
            console.log('odd call');
        } else {
            console.log('even call');
        }
    }
})();
```

This has the advantage of encapsulating the `calls` variable: that can't be accessed or tampered without outside of the function.

As a cautionary note, what this achieves is called a "side effect": that is, the behavior of the function can no longer be predicted without understanding the details of the function.  I'm not going to be dogmatic and say side effects are always bad, but you do have to be careful with them: make sure they make sense, and that your documentation is clear about what's happening.

Comment: The simplest way to add state to a function is a closure, why so much emphasis on objects instead?

Comment: Because an object makes it clear that there _is_ state.  If you were to take a purely functional attitude towards programming, functions should always return the same thing given the same inputs.  Closures break that formality.  I'm not saying that's a bad thing, necessarily, but objects do advertise themselves as having that functionality, whereas functions are generally expected to be more consistent.

Comment: The object solution is an answer to a different question. If I need to pass the function to someone else that expects a function to call, then the object is useless (because the caller would need to use `o.fn(...)`) or I need to pass a closure anyway. If you're in the "pure function" camp and you refuse the idea that the pc you're using right now has probably quite a few gigabytes of pure distilled state then I'd say it's better to just leave javascript alone and join the Haskell army, where the religion imposes hiding the state necessity under a monadic carpet.

Comment: You raise good points, 6502, but not in a very polite or constructive way.  You'll note I didn't say _not_ to use pure functions (I try not to be dogmatic about that), so I think your jab at the "pure function" camp was uncalled for.  I find it kind of amusing that you're calling the Haskell principles a "religion" (in the pejorative sense) at the same time you're thrusting your pitchfork at me.

Answer (score 1):

you'd need an index variable outside of the function scope.
something like this:

```
var index = 0;

function myFunction() {
    // TRUE on every second call
    if (++index % 2 === 0) {
        if (condition) {
             // ....
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure: instead of

```
function f(x, y, z) {
    ... normal processing ...
}
```

create a closure that every other call will do the check

```
var f = (function(){
           var do_check = true;
           return function(x, y, z){
               do_check = !do_check;
               if (do_check && ... check ...) {
                  ... special handling ...
               } else {
                  ... normal processing ...
               };
          })();
```

As others said however I'd say that keeping this behavior hidden inside the function seems a bad idea. Probably a better solution is just externalize (and document) the state.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question.

For sure there will be answers that tell you how to do this, but I'd argue that *"The only winning move is not to play."*

Having functions that behave differently between calls make will make your software very hard to work with (maintain, test, debug, reason about).

Should there be a reason for needing the function to behave differently between calls, make it about the state of the system, not purely about the function itself.

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't make the function behave differently in regards to itself, as in, change it's own code on different calls?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with pkyeck, but why increase a var.

```
var checkCall = 1;
function myfunction(){
    if(checkCall){
        alert('true: so no code will run');
        checkCall = 0;
    } else {
        alert('run the code');
        checkCall = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: IIUC the original question the requirement is that every other call the check is performed. Your code does the check only once and never again for subsequent calls.